# How to use a boxcar averager in conjunction with lock-in amplifier

Tags: noise, phase, snr

Suppose there exists a temporal voltage signal composed of short pulses, modulated by a sinusoidal envelope. One desires a hardware-based signal processing scheme to maximize signal to noise ratio (SNR) measured at both (a) the frequency (repetition rate) of the pulses and (b) at the frequency of the modulation. The two standard methods for signal detection are:

(1) Lock-in amplifier: it's best to use this device when the signal being measured is close to a sinusoid. Ideally, the duty cycle is 50%. Phase-sensitive detection using a reference signal produced by the source allows for optimized SNR.

(2) Boxcar averager: it's best to use this device when the signal being measured has a low duty cycle. A temporal gate is applied to exclude regions where noise is known to dominate.

Now back to the signal at hand, illustrated in the following figure:

[image]

The signal is composed of two key features:

(a) Very low duty cycle pulses of voltage (blue), which describe the actual energy content of the signal.

(b) An almost ideal sinusoidal modulation (red) that forms an envelope about the pulses. The duty cycle of the modulation is near 50%. This envelope exists because, before being detected, the pulses are passed through a device that modulates their amplitude in a sinusoidal fashion.

Both the source (high repetition rate generator of pulses) and the modulating device provide reference trigger signals. These reference signals are synchronized to the repetition rate of the pulses and the modulation frequency, respectively. One can use these reference signals, e.g., to demodulate at both frequencies using a lock-in.

Since signal (a) is well-suited for the boxcar strategy, and detection of (b) would be optimal via lock-in detection, how can one leverage both detection schemes to optimize SNR? The goal is to measure the magnitudes of the signal at both the pulse repetition rate and the modulation frequency.

One might suggest to split the signal in two, then send half into a boxcar and half into a lock-in. The boxcar can isolate the magnitude of the pulses optimally. The lock-in can isolate the magnitude of the modulation component. However, since the modulation component is an envelope composed of the short pulses, the lock-in strategy is necessarily suboptimal (low duty cycles aren't great for lock-ins).

Comment: "The device modulating the pulses can also provide a reference trigger" -- do you mean the thing generating the pulses will tell you when the pulse happens, or will give you a signal synchronized with the modulating sine wave?  Please _edit your question_ to incorporate the answer.

Comment: (+1) Interesting! Long ago, I tried something like this. I had a low duty factor stream of laser-induced signal pulses, about 10 ns pulse widths, and usually just detected them with an EG&G PARC boxcar averager (BA). The rep rate was about 30 Hz, if I remember right. But I wanted to try lock-in amplifier (LIA) detection, so I pulse-stretched the signal pulses to get a far more favorable duty factor. It worked, but I don’t think the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) was as high as just using the BA because pulse stretching has an SNR downside. It will be interesting to see a good answer here!